# How to count string in columns using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have following dataset.

```
game_id h_abbr a_abbr 
0001    WSH    TOR 
0002    ANA    TOR 
0003    TOR    MIN
```

I want to count how many games each team has played so far. Output should be like this

```
game_id h_abbr a_abbr ht_game_no at_game_no
0001    WSH    TOR    1          1
0002    ANA    TOR    1          2
0003    TOR    MIN    3          1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) for `MultiIndex Series`, then use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) for counter, reshape by [`Series.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html), add `rename` and add to original DataFrame by [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html):

```
s = df.set_index('game_id')[['h_abbr','a_abbr']].stack()

d = {'h_abbr':'ht_game_no','a_abbr':'at_game_no'}
df = df.join(s.groupby(s).cumcount().add(1).unstack().rename(columns=d), on='game_id')
print (df)
   game_id h_abbr a_abbr  ht_game_no  at_game_no
0        1    WSH    TOR           1           1
1        2    ANA    TOR           1           2
2        3    TOR    MIN           3           1
```

Comment: sorry without description it is not so clear

Comment: @BrownBear - I looking for better solution, now add desc.

Comment: What's `s.groupby(s)`? I never saw `groupby` self before.

Comment: @tdy - It is trick for groupby by `Series` if need grouping by their values.

Comment: @tdy - But it is rare use.